# Update A Partial View From Another Partial View - ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I want to have **two partial views**, one for `SEARCH` and one for `SEARCHRESULTS`.

I want to update `SEARCHRESULTS` when the "Search" Button is clicked on the `SEARCH` partial view form.  `SEARCHRESULTS` needs to have the form data fed to it from the `SEARCH` partial view.

I'm not totally sure how to go about this.  Can I update the `SEARCHRESULTS` partial view from my `SEARCH` partial view's Controller action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**General Discussion**
In the MVC design pattern views are unaware of each other. They may be bound together by the concept of a view assembling multiple partial views but even then the partials are ignorant of each other. This concept is true for ASP.NET MVC. Mike Brind does a good job describing partials and ViewData in his post [ASP.NET MVC Partial Views and Strongly Typed Custom ViewModels](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels).

**Specific to your Question**
To answer your question a partial view can have a link to a controller action that renders a different view, so long as the appropriate information is passed to the controller. How you go about this will depend on what you are trying to do.

Given your question I am going to assume that the `SEARCH` partial view is a simple form with a search field and button. While `SEARCHRESULTS` is a listing of the returned data. In this instance you'd create a controller action called `Search` which takes in a string value and returns just the `SEARCHRESULTS` partial or a view containing the `SEARCHRESULTS` partial. Scott Guthrie provides a pretty good description of passing data to a view in his blog post [Passing ViewData from Controllers to Views](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx).

```
// returning partial
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
    //do search .......
    //.................

    return PartialView("SEARCHREULTS", viewdata);
}
```