# Update a partial view with a string from another partial view on submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC and Web Api, and getting stuck. 
Please Note: I am using ApiControllers, not Controllers!

**Situation**
I have two partial views. The first has drop down lists and a submit button. The second is just a confirmation view showing what the user selected after user submits. On clicking submit, I want to send a string (containing the user's combined selections) to the second partial view and update it.

**Question**
When I press submit on the first partial view, I want to send a string to the second partial view and update the second partial view. How can I do this? The sending of the string can be indirect, of course, like view to controller then back to view. I just want to know at least *one* way.

Again, note that I am using Web Api Controllers, NOT Controllers. Most people use normal Controllers, which doesn't apply to me. They are different.

**Things I tried / What I believe I cannot do from other StackOverflow answers:**

1. I cannot use a Controller method to return a Partial View, like in this very similarly asked question [Same question but not with ApiControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748287/update-a-partial-view-from-another-partial-view-asp-net-mvc2).
2. I cannot store any data into a class, so I cannot strongly type a view with @model ExampleClass to access stored contents with @Model.ExampleProperty.
3. Since I cannot store data into a class or return a model from a controller method like View(model), I also could not use Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue) to store the SelectedValue into my model and access it in the other partial view. Instead to populate my drop down lists, I manually added a div, called a GET method that returned a list, and populated the lists by appending to them.

So, what exactly CAN I do? I also tried ViewData, but the stored data would not last after a Controller method finished. I am out of ideas. I hope I am mistaken about something and missed a method, because it feels it should not be this hard. If you could even briefly describe the flow of how I would transfer a string and/or update the second partial view after pressing submit, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance!

**Model class**

```
public class Vehicle
    {
        public class Make
        {
            public int MakeId { get; set; }
            public string MakeName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public int ModelId { get; set; }
            public string ModelName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**ApiController class**. The ViewData seems to not save its contents. I wanted to store the user's selections into ViewData with the first POST method, and GET the selections with the second method, but the contents of ViewData have become null already.

```
public class VehicleController : ApiController
    {
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();

        [HttpPost]
        public void StoreMakeAndModel(string user_selections){
            ViewData["message"] = user_selections;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string ConfirmationMessage(){
            ViewData["message"] = "You selected the " + ViewData["message"].ToString();
            return ViewData["message"].ToString();
        }

        //This returns a list to populate a drop down list
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Vehicle.Make> Makes(){
            //This function reads from xml and returns List<Vehicle.Make>
            ...
            return makesList;
        }

        //This returns a list to populate a drop down list
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Vehicle.Model> Models(int id){
            //This function reads from xml the car models that match the make id
            ...
            return modelsList;
        }
    }
```

**First partial view** It has 2 drop down lists and submit button. There is a hidden div that shows once the form submits that renders the second partial view. I hoped that it would load only when it is shown so that I can use $(document).ready(function()) to display my string there, but it loads when the main page loads even though it's hidden. So I don't know how to update it with the string after the first partial view submits.

```
<select required id="makes_DDL" name="makes_DDL"></select>

<select required id="models_DDL" name="models_DDL"></select>

<input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit Form" onclick="formSubmit()" />

<div id="thank_you_div" style="display:none;">
    @Html.Partial("_ThankYou");
</div>

    function formSubmit() {
        //Combines the make and model into one string, Ex: Chevrolet Malibu
        var parameter = $("#makes_DDL").children(":selected").text() + " " 
             + $("#models_DDL").children(":selected").text();
        var uri = "api/vehicle/storemakeandmodel/" + parameter;

        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: "post",
            updatetargetid: "thank_you_div",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#thank_you_div").show();
            },
            });
}
```

My list population looks like this; this is my first list. I could not get @Html.DropDownListFor to work because I could not store anything since I cannot return something like View(model) from a controller method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("api/vehicle/makes", function (makes) {
            $("#makes_DDL").append("<option value= ''>Select a make</option>");
            $.each(makes, function (id, make) {
                $("#makes_DDL").append("<option value=" + make.MakeId + ">" + make.MakeName + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
```

**Second partial view** It tries to get the stored message in ViewData, but it is already gone and GETS null.

```
<div id="thank_you_div">Thank you!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Thank You Partial View ready!");
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/vehicle/confirmationmessage",
            type: "get",
            updatetargetid: "thank_you_div",
            success: function (message) {
                $("#thank_you_div").html(message)
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: How are you currently rendering the page which has the two drop downs ? Is It not via a controller action ?

Comment: Also why can't you get a response from your first ajax call and simply update some DOM element with the response and  show it ? `$("#thank_you_div").html(data).show()`. Remove the second partial view

Comment: There are 2 controller methods, each returns an IEnumerable of makes or models. Each method populates each of the 2 drop down lists in the first partial view. The way I populate it is, I use getJSON to return list from my controller methods, then loop through the makes or models with javascript, and append them 1 by 1 to a select element (makes_DDL and modesl_DDL are the element id's). So that they become actual drop down lists and not empty select elements.
I included my list population near the bottom.
Maybe this is inefficient...? But I could not figure out a different way for Web Api.

Comment: You still did not answer my question. Why do you even care of the second partial view. Have your first ajax call return the string you want (from `StoreMakeAndModel`) and in the success handler of that ajax call, udpate the DOM with the response (the string)

Comment: I will probably do that if I cannot figure out another way, but I'm trying to do it with partial views so I am trying to figure out a way. I agree that it seems much easier that way and serves the same purpose, but that's not what they challenged me to do haha. Also sorry I did not mean to ignore your question, just slow internet. I would like to learn or know if there is a way to do it to learn as well for the future. I feel there must be a way because otherwise ApiController seems to be very limiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your ApiController action methods.

```
[HttpPost]
public void StoreMakeAndModel(string user_selections)
{
   ViewData["message"] = user_selections;
}
[HttpGet]
public string ConfirmationMessage()
{
    ViewData["message"] = "You selected the " + ViewData["message"].ToString();
    return ViewData["message"].ToString();
}
```

Looks like you are trying to store data to ViewData when the first method is called and read it in the second method when you make your second ajax call. **But that will not work! Because http is stateless**. Your second call has no idea what your first call did. You cannot store data in ViewData  to access between multiple http requests. It does not make sense to use ViewData in an api controller at all. Api controller endpoints should be purely to return data.

In your case, what you should be doing is, simply have your first method return the string message you want. In the success handler of the first ajax call,you will get this string (Response from the api method) in the success call back. You can use this to update the DOM as needed.

There is no need to have the partial view as well. All you need is a container div element to show the response.

```
<select required id="makes_DDL" name="makes_DDL"></select>
<select required id="models_DDL" name="models_DDL"></select>

<input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit Form" onclick="formSubmit()" />

<div id="thank_you_div" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Now in your first ajax call's success callback, update the DOM with the response coming back.

Also `$.ajax` does not have a setting property called `updatetargetid` !

```
function formSubmit() {
    //Combines the make and model into one string, Ex: Chevrolet Malibu
    var parameter = $("#makes_DDL").children(":selected").text() + " " 
        + $("#models_DDL").children(":selected").text();
    var uri = "api/vehicle/?user_selections=" + parameter;
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "post"
    }).done(function(res) {
        $("#thank_you_div").html(res).show();
    }).fail(function(x, v, e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Assuming your api controller method returns the string you want

```
[HttpPost]
public string StoreMakeAndModel(string user_selections)
{
    return  "You selected the "+user_selections;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much shyju! I did not realize that's what it means to be stateless, but that explains a lot of my other confusions too! Thanks for including all the code too.

I am still curious though, especially with what you said about how it's stateless and that methods should only return data. Would it be safe to say that it sounds like it's impossible to do what I was asked to do, in regards to getting the string somehow from one partial view to another, at least if I were to stick with API Controllers and a RESTful web app?

Comment: It is possible to persist data between 2 calls (like storing data in somewhere like a table/file and read from there). But it kills the stateless nature of http.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses. That makes a lot of sense to me. The possible method you described doesn't sound like what they want from me at all, so it sounds like they misworded or overlooked something.